# VueJs, how to refresh the data that has been fetch through created function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I use the "then" and "catch" function on Promise Object without using asynchronous functions for easy and manageable parts of response instead of using the await and conditional if-else then check the status if is not a server-side error but I'm a bit confused on how to manage the "then" method of Promise Object to auto-refresh the data that has been fetch through created function and redefined in "then" method using filter without fetching again the data's on the backend side.

```
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Header,
    Tasks,
    AddTask
  },
  data() {
    return {
      tasks : [],
      showAddTask : false
    }
  },
  methods : {
    deleteTask(index) 
    {
        const that = this;
        const res = fetch(`api/tasks/${index}`, {
          method : "DELETE"
        });

        res.catch(e => alert("Error deleting task"));
        res.then(function() {
          
          /**
          * this is a part where I am a bit confused 
          **/

          that.tasks.filter(e => e.id !== index)

          /** 
          * I use this method but it is not working
          **/

          that.$forceUpdate();


        });

        return res;

    }, 
    async fetchTask()
    {
      const res = await fetch("api/tasks");
      const data = await res.json();
      return data;
    },
  },
  async created() {
    this.tasks = await this.fetchTask();
  }
}
```

Comment: `that.tasks.filter(` doesn't mutate data. It's a noop. There's nothing to refresh, `that.tasks` stays the same, you can debug it. In regular cases `$forceUpdate` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns a subset of the original array. It doesn't mutate the array in place, so you have to assign `filter`'s return value to `this.tasks`.

Also, no need to assign `that = this`. Just use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to capture the Vue instance context.

`deleteTask()` should look like this:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    deleteTask(index) {
      fetch(`api/tasks/${index}`, {
        method : "DELETE"
      }).then(() => {
        this.tasks = this.tasks.filter(e => e.id !== index)
      }).catch(e => alert("Error deleting task"));
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-deleting-a-list-item?file=src/App.vue)

Answer (score 2):

I notice a few things here.

One, you don't need an if-else when using async/await. The async/await equivalent of a promise then/catch is a try/catch block:

```js
try {
    const res = await fetch(...);
    // Do something with res (response)
} catch (err) {
    // Equivalent to promise catch, handle the error (err)
}
```

Second, if you use arrow functions in your current callbacks you don't need to capture `const that = this`. And your syntax is strange, you should ideally chain the .then and .catch:

```js
fetch(...)
    .then((res) => { // this is an arrow function
        this.tasks...
    })
    .catch((err) => { // again an arrow function
        // Handle the error
    });
```

Finally, `Array.prototype.filter` returns a new array with the filtered items. Since you're not using the result of `that.tasks.filter` nothing is really happening. Instead, do:

```js
this.tasks = this.tasks.filter(...)
```